# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forex_python'

Tags: python, currency, converters, modulenotfounderror, forex

As I was trying to practice building a Currency Converter python program, guided by one of the open resources, I installed `forex-python` and ensured it was installed:

```
$ pip freeze
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
colorgram.py==1.2.0
forex-python==1.8
idna==3.4
Pillow==9.4.0
prettytable==3.5.0
prettyTables==1.1.5
requests==2.28.1
simplejson==3.18.1
urllib3==1.26.13
wcwidth==0.2.5
```

Then the code was copied/pasted without further modification:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

c = CurrencyRates()
amount = int(input("Enter the amount: "))
from_currency = input("From Currency: ").upper()
to_currency = input("To Currency: ").upper()
print(from_currency, " To ", to_currency, amount)
result = c.convert(from_currency, to_currency, amount)
print(result)
wcwidth==0.2.5
```

But the module was still missing; I even reinstalled forex-python several times.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Project002_Real-time_CurrencyConverter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forex_python'
```

I've searched on Google and couldn't find suitable solutions,
am I missing anything here, please?

**Updates:** 07/01/2023
Thanks for all the comments!! It's my first question; I sincerely appreciate all the feedback.

1. pip was installed under python3.11; after following the suggested commands for version check, my interpreter was python 3.9; I have shifted it to python 3.11. Just in case, I installed pip under python 3.9 too.

```
mac/~~$where python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
mac/~~$where python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
mac/~~$python -m pip install forex-python
```

I used PyCharm to run the code, and neither interpreter worked. The same message ModuleNotFoundError. But I did the same on VS Code, (checked interpreter, check python version), it worked finally.

Thank you all!

Comment: hmm looks OK. Can you try importing everything like this >> from forex_python import *

Comment: If it still doesn't work, try installing another common module in the same way, if you are still having the same issue, suspect it's some path/dir issue

Comment: You have two (or more) versions of Python installed on your computer. pip installed the module for one version of Python, but you're using a different version of Python to run the code.

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip --version` and also this code `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: @MattEng Really?  I've seen e.g. `python3` as a command, and sometimes `python3.8`, but I can't say I've ever seen `python-3.8`.  What system do you work with that has this?

Comment: Good catch! Made a typo

Comment: Fixed: In the event that you have multiple versions of Python, and pip is installing for the wrong one, you can specify your version with `pythonX.X -m pip install forex-python` where `X.X` is your system's version number.

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with imports and it worked for me. It seems like an issue with the install location.

Try running `pip show forex-python` to get your path (`location`). Then run, say, `pip show Pillow` to get the path of another package you know was installed correctly and you can import. Compare the two paths and ensure they’re in the same place.

If you're still unable install it with pip, just download the `.tar` from PyPI and manually load it.